# How can I add a functional delete button and a textbox to this simple .php delete script?

Tags: php, html, mysql

The admin will type the username of the member and hit delete button to remove the member from the database

```
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "phplogin");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Attempt delete query execution

$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username='mrs.snowballs'";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records were deleted successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Java **IS NOT** JavaScript.

Comment: What is the javascript's purpose here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='simple.php' method='post'>
    What Name You want to delete : <input type='text' name='del'/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='delete'/>
</form>
```

Now In Your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  $name = $_POST['del'];
   $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "phplogin");

   // Check connection
     if($link === false){
     die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

      // Attempt delete query execution

    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username='$name'";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records were deleted successfully.";
    } else{
   echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }


    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
 }
```

Comment: oops sorry about that

Comment: it worked. Now how do you mirror the database to a table into the page so the manger knows what to delete?

id name username date

Comment: i cant understand please elaborate this